# pyqtgraph : I want to execute pyqtgraph in new process

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph, multiprocess

Dear pyqtgraph masters,

I want to execute pyqtgraph in a newly created process.

In my project there is a python module : trading.py. This module makes a new process using this code

```
p = Process(target = realDataProcess.realDataProcessStart, args=(self.TopStockList, self.requestCodeList, self.account))
```

And you know, To maintain pyqtgraph displaying the computer moniter, we have to use pyqt loop like below.

```
QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

But in new process, It seems that Above code doesn't work. My graph pops up and suddenly disappear.....

Is there any solution about this? please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with multiprocess and pyqtgraph is, that you can't create a new pyqtgraph window on new processes.
Therefore, you can only use pyqtgrahp on your **main process**.
I think there was the explanation somewhere on the net.

If you want to create additional processes to do something, besides pyqtgraph, put your pyqtgraph code below if **name** == '**main**':
Otherwise, you will have as many windows as you have processes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the class *RemoteGraphicsView*, which uses the *Multiprocessing utility library*.

> > **Multiprocessing utility library**
>
> This library provides:
>
> - simple mechanism for starting a new python interpreter process that can be controlled from the original process
>   (this allows, for example, displaying and manipulating plots in a remote process
>   while the parent process is free to do other work)
> - proxy system that allows objects hosted in the remote process to be used as if they were local
> - Qt signal connection between processes
> - very simple in-line parallelization (fork only; does not work on windows) for number-crunching

You can actually use this class to make a graph that execute on a new process in a second window if you want.

Take a look at these two examples [examples/RemoteGraphicsView.py](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/examples/RemoteGraphicsView.py) and [examples/RemoteSpeedTest.py](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/examples/RemoteSpeedTest.py)